# Игры на улучшение. Как сбалансировать?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, балансировка

Понимаю, что не по теме. Но не знаю где еще  можно спросить.

Учу unity, c#

Решил для начала создать игру "на улучшение". Такие игры, где зарабатываешь деньги, покупаешь улучшения чтобы заработать еще больше денег чтобы купить больше улучшений и переходить на новые уровни.

Вижу что подобные игры работают по примерно одинаковой балансировке, каждый уровень все сложнее и сложнее. Но не могу понять по какому именно принципу / формуле усложняется и замедляется игра.

Возможно есть где-то подходящий форум, где можно спросить, статья хорошая или собственный опыт - буду очень благодарен за информацию!!

Comment: Нет единой формулы, каждая игра на вкус создателя. Попробуйте сами в нее поиграть или дайте друзьям, чтобы узнать их мнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно не по теме, для такого есть  [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Эти игры называются одним словом `idle` или по умному `Incremental game`
 (инкрементальные игры).

Примерно одинаковый "баланс" это банальный `экспоненциальный рост`.

Тупо загуглив `how do idle game` уйма статей. например [kongregate](https://blog.kongregate.com/the-math-of-idle-games-part-i/).